# how many is too many Kafka commits per second

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I have read that you shouldn't commit offsets with the Kafka high level consumer too often as each commit is a write to Zookeeper and so you can slow down Zookeeper because it's strongly consistent across its quorum.

My question is, what is considered a lot of writes to Zookeeper?  I am sending 10 messages per second and it would make my system a lot nicer if I could afford to commit after every message but is this a lot?  I really don't know.  I would ideally like some idea before I start testing on our fully loaded kafka cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this graph, you can see, that their example setup (3x dual 2Ghz Xeon and two SATA 15K RPM drives) can handle ~80000 writes/s if you have only writes.

[image]

source: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ZooKeeper/Performance